# Can't GET JSONObject from server method(Iternal server error 500)

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm working on java Spring Boot app with serverside pagination and i've met problem. When I'm getting all data from localhost:8080/tabelka everything is good, but when i want to GET data from localhost:8080/pgTabelka postMAN is returning this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-23T10:58:42.963+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/pgTabelka"
}
```

my controller:

```
package com.example.controller;


import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.dao.SeriaDao;
import com.example.model.Seria;


@RestController
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    SeriaDao sed;

    HttpServletRequest request;


    @GetMapping("/tabelka")
    public List<Seria> showTable()
    {
        return sed.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/pgTabelka")
    public JSONObject pgTable()
    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        int draw = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("draw"));
        int start = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("start"));
        int length = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("length"));
        int totalRecords = sed.recordsTotal();
        List<Seria> serie = sed.findPart(start, length);

        try {
            json.put("draw", ++draw);
            json.put("recordsTotal", totalRecords);
            json.put("recordsFiltered", totalRecords);
            json.put("data", serie);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }
}
```

May be you can help me find error. My console in application is returnint "ERROR 14496 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause" but i am not sure that this is connected with what i wrote. Thanks for help guys!

EDIT:
I changed code like this and there is not ERROR in console

```
int draw = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int length = 10;

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        if(request.getParameter("draw")!=null)
            draw = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("draw"));
        if(request.getParameter("start")!=null)
            start = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("start"));
        if(request.getParameter("length")!=null)
            length = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("length"));
```

And now POSTman is returning

```
{
    "empty": false
}
```

EDIT2:
I printed json variable and i get this:

```
{"recordsFiltered":488,"data":[{"feed":"Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets","unit":"$ per Week","file":"SMU48185800500000011.csv","cassid":"1d2e556b-031e-4c6f-aec4-981c4e907324","name":"Average Weekly Earnings of All Employees: Total Private in Corpus Christi, TX (MSA)","createdate":"2016-10-15T23:38:49","changedate":"2017-01-09T00:50:01","id":41,"datefrom":"2006-12-31","categoryid":3,"frequency":5},{"feed":"Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets","unit":"Index 2015=100","file":"CP0910CYM086NEST.csv","cassid":"6df5b8d5-ec39-4860-930f-a8b355cce37a","name":"Harmonized Index of Consumer Prices: Audio-Visual, Photographic, and Information Processing Equipment for Cyprus","createdate":"2016-10-15T23:38:49","changedate":"2017-02-16T11:35:04","id":42,"datefrom":"1995-12-31","categoryid":3,"frequency":5},{"feed":"Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets","unit":"$ per Week","file":"SMU48185800500000011A.csv","cassid":"c3bad2a6-7ad5-4091-846b-f84e9b9f7b50","name":"Average Weekly Earnings of All Employees: Total Private in Corpus Christi, TX (MSA)","createdate":"2016-10-15T23:38:49","changedate":"2017-02-16T11:32:01","id":43,"datefrom":"2006-12-31","categoryid":3,"frequency":8},{"feed":"Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets","unit":"Index 2015=100","file":"CP0910CZM086NEST.csv","cassid":"84483d95-d914-45ab-a87a-8c063bfc6d0f","name":"Harmonized Index of Consumer Prices: Audio-Visual, Photographic, and Information Processing Equipment for Czech Republic","createdate":"2016-10-15T23:38:49","changedate":"2017-02-16T11:35:04","id":44,"datefrom":"1999-11-30","categoryid":3,"frequency":5},{"feed":"Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets","unit":"$ per Week","file":"SMU41187000500000011SA.csv","cassid":"285056e3-94ce-4266-98b4-ddf32602c0c2","name":"Average Weekly Earnings of All Employees: Total Private in Corvallis, OR (MSA)","createdate":"2016-10-15T23:38:49","changedate":"2017-01-09T00:50:01","id":45,"datefrom":"2006-12-31","categoryid":3,"frequency":5},{"feed":"Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets","unit":"Index 2015=100","file":"CP0910DKM086NEST.csv","cassid":"9798eadf-1503-48a5-91e3-cad5852db745","name":"Harmonized Index of Consumer Prices: Audio-Visual, Photographic, and Information Processing Equipment for Denmark","createdate":"2016-10-15T23:38:49","changedate":"2017-02-16T11:35:04","id":46,"datefrom":"1995-12-31","categoryid":3,"frequency":5},{"feed":"Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets","unit":"$ per Week","file":"SMU41187000500000011.csv","cassid":"d4b22376-2f84-404f-a175-c04ad8ced5a5","name":"Average Weekly Earnings of All Employees: Total Private in Corvallis, OR (MSA)","createdate":"2016-10-15T23:38:49","changedate":"2017-01-09T00:50:01","id":47,"datefrom":"2006-12-31","categoryid":3,"frequency":5},{"feed":"Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets","unit":"Index 2015=100","file":"CP0910EEM086NEST.csv","cassid":"72880ba0-722e-46bb-98f4-7d388d217c26","name":"Harmonized Index of Consumer Prices: Audio-Visual, Photographic, and Information Processing Equipment for Estonia","createdate":"2016-10-15T23:38:49","changedate":"2017-02-16T11:35:04","id":48,"datefrom":"1995-12-31","categoryid":3,"frequency":5},{"feed":"Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets","unit":"$ per Week","file":"SMU41187000500000011A.csv","cassid":"03fdf50e-9cd9-483b-aecf-1a0a9e93fa4d","name":"Average Weekly Earnings of All Employees: Total Private in Corvallis, OR (MSA)","createdate":"2016-10-15T23:38:49","changedate":"2017-02-16T11:32:01","id":49,"datefrom":"2006-12-31","categoryid":3,"frequency":8},{"feed":"Macroeconomic_And_Major_Markets","unit":"Index 2005=100","file":"CP0910EZ17M086NEST.csv","cassid":"2943c0f2-ad55-4ec4-98d0-70db25deaefc","name":"Harmonized Index of Consumer Prices: Audio-Visual, Photographic, and Information Processing Equipment for Euro area (17 countries) (DISCONTINUED)","createdate":"2016-10-15T23:38:49","changedate":"2017-02-16T11:35:04","id":50,"datefrom":"1995-12-31","categoryid":3,"frequency":5}],"draw":1,"recordsTotal":488}
```

So it looks everything is good but why draw is not first in this json object if i added it first? And why POSTman is getting "empty"?

Comment: The NullPointerException should be pointing to a file and a line number. Check that file and line number. If you have something like someObject(), someObject is null. If you have something like someObject().callOnReturnedObject(), likely someObject() is returning a null value.

Comment: Can you provide some more information? The request you send via Postman and the full stack trace from the service log would be very helpful.

Comment: @Michael yes.
GET localhost:8080/pgTabelka
And getting:
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-23T11:47:37.039+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "null",
    "path": "/pgTabelka"
}

Comment: @Juan there is no parameters, you need to add those. At least `draw`, `start` and `length`.

Comment: @Michael I want to get parameters like draw, start and length from DataTables. But may be i'm doing this wrong...

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with HttpServletRequest which you have initialized.
It should be passed as method argument instead of initializing in class level.

> public JSONObject pgTable(HttpServletRequest request)

Your Answer for the second problem regarding order of parameter in response can be solved by using

> @ResponseBody USER_DEFINED_CLASS getData()

and inside USER_DEFINED_CLASS you can make use of

> @XmlType(proporder="")

for more reference

1. @ResponseBody :[click here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body)
2. @XmlType :[click here](https://dzone.com/articles/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder)

@XmlType annotation is itself enough no need to use any other annotation from example 2 mentioned above

Comment: Thanks, you have right, but it's nothing changed for me now :/

Comment: Or i was wrong. Now i have something like this:
"ERROR 18272 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: null] with root cause"

Comment: do null check for request.getParameter("parameterName") like this
if(request.getParameter("parameterName")!=null){
  parseToINT......
}

Comment: i did it and now POSTMan is returning "{
    "empty": false
}"

Comment: Returning "{ "empty": false }" although variable named json is not empty, is not null, have data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume one of the parameters was not given in your request. E.g. the line

Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("draw"))

throws a `NullPointerException` if the request has no parameter `draw`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have Request Object before getting parameters like below.

```
@GetMapping("/pgTabelka")
    public JSONObject pgTable(HttpServletRequest request)
    {

}
```

Put a breakpoint on this line `JSONObject json = new JSONObject();` and debug it line by line.

This is happening because one of the parameters draw,start,length are coming null.

Once you resolve NullPointerException ,you may get NumberFormatException also so to prevent that check the values before converting to integer whether they are convertible to change to integer.

Comment: Yea, you are right parameters probably are null. But i don't understand exacly how should i fix it...

Comment: make sure your request body JSON contains all 3 fields with some values.

Comment: look at EDIT please. it looks like this 3 fields are not null, but "empty"?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that before parsing into Integer parameter should not be null

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/pgTabelka", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONObject pgTable(HttpServletRequest request)
        {
           //validate request parameter before converting it into Integer
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my post, fields looks like not null...

Comment: @PawełMałysz have you check your return JSON object is creating properly ?(make it sysout before returning)

Comment: add @ResponseBody and check

Comment: I added it like:@ResponseBody
 @GetMapping("/pgTabelka")
 public JSONObject pgTable(HttpServletRequest request)
 {" And still the same, nothing changed